# Schema.org, correct Attributes for a School Undergraduate Program

Tags: schema.org, rdfa

I am unsure as to how I should attribute a school's programs.

I need to denote the top level, so Graduate vs. Undergraduate and then subs of those items, so Graduate -> Art or Undergraduate -> Java Programming.

I am assuming I would be using

Thing > Organization > EducationalOrganization > CollegeOrUniversity

Or

Thing > Event > EducationEvent

Has anyone had to categorize this kind of information before? If so, what categories did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CollegeOrUniversity`](http://schema.org/CollegeOrUniversity) is for the *organization*, not for something that this organization does or has.

[`EducationEvent`](http://schema.org/EducationEvent) seems to be appropriate.

You could specify the `CollegeOrUniversity` as [`organizer`](http://schema.org/organizer) of the `EducationEvent`.

Apart from [`typicalAgeRange`](http://schema.org/typicalAgeRange), `EducationEvent` doesn’t offer properties to denote the target audience of the event. So specifying that it’s for "Graduate vs. Undergraduate" would have to happen informally, e.g., in the `name` or the `description`.